# Android emulator not being able to interact with local rest APIs?

Tags: android, asp.net, api, rest, android-emulator

So, is there some kind of setup to be made if you want to have a rest API working in the android emulator? To be mentioned is that my emulator has access to the internet and can access links on chrome and web test browser(I'm working in visual studio and trying to develop an asp.net web rest API)
So far I tried a bunch of stuff and none made a difference:

- Try running projects both in Visual Studio and Android Studio
- Cold boot the emulator from both ide
- Add internet/network permissions in the androidManifest files
- Try to run projects w the rest APIs that are supposed to be working as intended
- Try to change DNS
- Change the localhost address to 10.0.2.2

So far nothing works, the emulator neither in the browser nor in the app doesn’t see the local API
Did anyone have such a problem and found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your firewall settings, preferably turn it off.